# Blackberry: Changing background color of a screen's menu?

Tags: blackberry, menu, background, default, customizing

Is it possible to change the background color of a screen's menu from the blueish-grayish color that is the default?

Comment: Once with API 4.7.0 I tried to do this but without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ***public void setBackground(Background background)*** [net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Menu] to change the background. A Null value will provide default background (system theme). (since BlackBerry **API 5.0.0**)